# How to view through C# WinForm from another WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a capture app in C# with winforms.
I'm trying to see through a winform from another winform.

What I have now is this:
[image: screenshot]

The black background with the opacity is **winform number 1**

And the blue rectangle with Transparent Fill is in **winform number 2**

I need a way to see the content of the website page through winform 1.

This is what i'm trying to accomplish :
[image: how is should be]

I already tried to set the Fill Color to the Transparent Key Color like this:

**This is TransparencyKey code for winform number 1:**

```
this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;
```

**This is the code that draw the rectangle on winform number 2:**

```
SolidBrush TransparentBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent);
Pen MyPen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);

private void ThePaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            g.FillRectangle(TransparentBrush, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);
            g.DrawRectangle(MyPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);
            RectangleDrawn = true;
        }
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off using WPF for this.

Comment: I WISH!, But I Can't use WPF for this.

Comment: 1.it's already finish. 2.I knew about WPF only after I started with Winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting a panel on your form 2 and then setting it's colour to "Pink" - that way, it will be transparent through the form 2 to the web page behind.  The only downside is that it does look odd if you have any controls on it.  All this is achievable through the WinForm designer.

Comment: `"that way, it will be transparent through the form 2 to the web page behind."`   Did you mean from 1? Cos I need it to see through the black opacity winform

Comment: No worries - glad it helped!  Sorry I wasn't about to reply to your comment.